# ScrollLeft in percentage

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to make a div scroll when a button(.arrow_right) is clicked. The code below works perfectly fine, but I want to scroll in percentage instead of pixels. Is this even possible?

```html
$('.arrow_right').click(function()
{
    $('.gallery .inside').animate( { scrollLeft: '+=450' }, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do it,

```
var page = 0;

$('.arrow_right').click(function()
{
    switch(page) {
        case 0:
            $('.gallery .inside').animate( { left: '0%' }, 200);
        break;
        case 1:
            $('.gallery .inside').animate( { left: '-100%' }, 200);
        break;
    }
    page++;
})
```